# rake doesn't work when using swagger-docs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger

I'm using swagger-docs sample to generate my api docs, at the beginning, everything went well. but today when I use "rake swagger:docs" after I change something in controller, nothing happened.
There is no error alert. After I start the server and type url in browser, the UI didn't show what I want.
Is there any special configuration I need to do? or please just tell me how to generate the docs properly.

Comment: did you get any resolution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I figured it out. But I am using AWS EC2. Just for someone may need it.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake swagger:docs
```